# What should we keep in mind while editing a question or answer?

Tags: discussion

Recently I have started editing questions and answers on Stack Overflow more frequently. I have noticed that some of my edits will be approved and some get rejected.

**What I think is like when some of my changes related to grammar or code will be approved and some of with similar edit will get rejected.** so please anyone tell me what rules should I follow to edit the post.

What should I do when question or answer is too short, but it has some mistake or it will require an edit?

Just to point out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16784747) is one of my edits is which approved by some reviewer and rejected by the community.

Comment: I have to look back at my edits to find it but most of the time some highlight of code or removing `thank` or stuff like that will be getting rejected.

Comment: If you want to freely edit such posts where the post itself is too short or does not meet editor requirements, you will have to get to 2k rep where your edits wont need reviewing..

Comment: yes, i just find out while searching for this issue. thanks for pointing that out.  @suraj

Comment: reviewers may reject changes when either the change itself is not significant enough to improve the post..or where you may have missed a lot of other changes. There are a variety of reasons.. you have very few rejections.. Not really see a problem.

Comment: one of the recent incidents of rejecting is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16784747) and has some other also.

Comment: That is not because of a reviewer.. It is a community reject.. meaning OP edited the post and changed it before your edit review was completed. So the community bot automatically rejects it. In fact you already had one approval

Comment: ok i think that this discussion has no end.  should I delete this question now? @suraj

Comment: why would you want to delete it? You could wait for the others in the community to weigh in if you want. Its upto you.

Comment: One thing I noticed about your edits: use code-markdown for code only ( and for stacktraces), don't use it to highlight product-names or other things.

Comment: @piet.t thanks for the suggestion I will surely keep that in mind.